# How to read csv file which has column delimiter as well record delimiter

Tags: python, pandas

My CSV file has 3 columns: Name,Age and Sex and sample data is:

```
AlexÇ39ÇM
#Ç#SheebaÇ35ÇF
#Ç#RiyaÇ10ÇF
```

The column delimiter is 'Ç' and record delimiter is '#Ç#'. Note the first record don't  have the record delimiter(#Ç#), but all other records have record delimiter(#Ç#). Could you please tell me how to read this file and store it in a dataframe?

Comment: That doesn't look like a CSV. The delimiters per row should be consistent. Even if `AlexÇ39ÇM` was the header, it should use the same delimiter

Comment: @sietse85, thanks for the input. i am new to python, could please give me the sample code for your suggestion?.

Comment: hmm somehow i got to your question with php tag... but ok :)

Comment: @sietse85: AFAIK `fgetcsv` is a PHP-function, not a Python one. However, reading csv-files with consistent delimiters can be read using the Python built-in [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module or [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) as an external module with additional features.

Comment: @Alexsander: What do you mean with 'record delimiter' and 'column delimiter'?

Comment: @albert, each column is split by 'Ç' and each record is split by #Ç#. note that first record dont have '#Ç#', but remaining record will have it in the beginning of the line. please refer my sample record.

Comment: @Alexsander: What _is_ a record? Are there more than one record per line/row?

Comment: @albert, a record is a line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `csv` and `pandas` module support reading csv-files directly. However, since you need to modify the file contents line by line before further processing, I suggest reading the file line by line, modify each line as desired and store the processed data in a list for further handling.

The necessary steps include:

- open file
- read file line by line
- remove newline char (which is part of the line when using `readlines()`
- replace record delimiter (since a record is equivalent to a line)
- split lines at column delimiter

Since `.split()` returns a list of string elements we get an overall list of lists, where each 'sub-list' contains/represents the data of a line/record. Data formatted like this can be read by `pandas.DataFrame.from_records()` which comes in quite handy at this point:

```
import pandas as pd

with open('myData.csv') as file:
    # `.strip()` removes newline character from each line
    # `.replace('#;#', '')` removes '#;#' from each line
    # `.split(';')` splits at given string and returns a list with the string elements
    lines = [line.strip().replace('#;#', '').split(';') for line in file.readlines()]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(lines, columns=['Name', 'Age', 'Sex'])

print(df)
```

Remarks:

1. I changed `Ç` to `;` which worked better for me due to encoding issues. However, the basic idea of the algorithm is still the same.
2. Reading data manually like this can become quite resource-intensive which might be a problem when handling larger files. There might be more elegant ways, which I am not aware of. When getting problems with performance, try to read the file in chunks or have a look for more effective implementations.